# Why percent signs (%) do not work in crontab?

Tags: linux, bash, date, cron

I'm writing files out to a log ran by a bash script using cron. The call on cron looks like this:

```
*/25 * * * * bash script.sh > "/var/log/$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M).log"
```

But when I check the crontab it records as

```
*/25 * * * * bash script.sh > "/var/log/$(date +).log"
```

And it never writes the log file. Is there something I need to change to get cron to write the date?

Answer (score 8):

It is a matter of escaping variables:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/touch /tmp/$(date +\%Y:\%m).log
#                                      ^   ^
```

worked to me.

From `man 5 crontab`:

> Percent-signs (%) in the command, unless  escaped  with  backslash (\), will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the first % will be sent to the command as standard input.

So

```
*/25 * * * * /bin/bash script.sh > "/var/log/$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d_\%H:\%M).log"
#                                                    ^    ^   ^   ^   ^
```

should work.

<sub>Note I used `/bin/bash` instead of just `bash`.</sub>