# date +"%Y-%m-%d" in crontab

Tags: date, centos, cron

If I put the following in `crontab -e`:

```
* * * * * date +"%Y-%m-%d" > /home/apps/temp/env.txt
```

there is no `env.txt` created.

If I change the above line to:

```
* * * * * date > /home/apps/temp/env.txt
```

`env.txt` is created properly.

How can I format `date` in cron?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why percent signs (%) do not work in crontab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16238460/why-percent-signs-do-not-work-in-crontab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape each one of the `%`:

```
* * * * * date +"\%Y-\%m-\%d" > /home/apps/temp/env.txt
```

Or even better, remove the quotes and leave like this:

```
* * * * * date +\%Y-\%m-\%d > /home/apps/temp/env.txt
```