# Ubuntu crontab script not working

Tags: linux, cron, ubuntu-13.10

I have 2 crontab commands.

The cron below works fine:

```
00 19 * * * cp -a /home/kmportal/VirtualBox\ VMs/cyn.in-disk1.vmdk /media/windowsshare
```

The cron below does not work after I add the time behind:

```
05 09 * * * cp -a /home/kmportal/VirtualBox\ VMs/cyn.in-disk1.vmdk /media/windowsshare/'date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S'cyn.in-disk1.vmdk
```

Please guide me to understand the command and how to solve.

Comment: possible duplicate of [date +"%Y-%m-%d" in crontab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21749305/date-y-m-d-in-crontab)

Answer (score 0):

You should enclose the date command with ` instead of ' and escape the % characters

Try this:

```
05 09 * * * cp -a /home/kmportal/VirtualBox\ VMs/cyn.in-disk1.vmdk /media/windowsshare/`date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S`cyn.in-disk1.vmdk
```