# Bash script to download data from url

Tags: bash, csv, cron, wget

I have a URL from which I have to download data on daily basis, e.g.: `www.manishshukla.com/files/05-17-2016.csv`

In the above URL, it gives me data for 17th May 2016. Similarly for the data of 18th May 2016, URL will be: `www.manishshukla.com/files/05-18-2016.csv`

I want Bash script, which will automatically takes the date of the day and downloads the file.

Please help me how to do it. I want to add this job on `cron` also, so that I don't need to manually run the code.

Comment: Honestly, who has upvoted this awful question. There is no specific problem, they are just asking someone to write a script for them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two bits here. One is to schedule a cron job and the other is to get the file & save it.

Steps :

1. Open the terminal & run `crontab -e`

   `minute(0-59) hour(0-23) day(1-31) month(1-12) weekday(0-6) command`
2. In place of minute, hour, day, month & weekday. Also provide the command to run.
3. The command to put up here is : `wget www.manishshukla.com/files/"$(date '+\%d-\%m-\%Y')".csv`
4. Save the file & the jobs are scheduled.

**In your case :**

```
0 0 * * * wget --quiet -O www.manishshukla.com/files/"$(date '+\%d-\%m-\%Y')".csv
```

OR

```
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/curl www.manishshukla.com/files/"$(date '+\%d-\%m-\%Y')".csv
```

This would run the command every day at 0hrs 0mins.

Added `\` to escape `%`, as it may not work in corntab without escaping.

> Percent-signs (%) in the command, unless escaped with backslash (),
>   will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the first
>   % will be sent to the command as standard input.

Comment: I understood scheduling it on cron, I need the complete bash script. So that I can run it in my terminal also for previous dates also.

Comment: It starts from today & goes on. If you want it for the previous dates then just write a for loop to put appropriate date and get the files with `wget` or `curl`

Comment: Note this will probably not work: you need to escape the `%` in the cron expression: [Why percent signs (%) do not work in crontab?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16238460/1983854).

Comment: @fedorqui Thanks, added it to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
wget www.manishshukla.com/files/"$(date '+%d-%m-%Y')".csv
```

If you want to save it somewhere specific, then

```
wget www.manishshukla.com/files/"$(date '+%d-%m-%Y')".csv -P /path/to/dir
```

You can put this command in a daily cron to download the files in a daily basis. For cron, use the full path of `wget` i.e `/usr/bin/wget` or `/usr/local/bin/wget` or whatever it is.

Comment: Can you please provide me the complete code, from start as well as saving of downloaded file.