# CRON JOB - How to grab image from URL ...servlet/byvejr_dag1?by=5466&mode=long

Tags: cron

I want to save an image from another server with a CRON job
URL: http://servlet.dmi.dk/byvejr/servlet/byvejr_dag1?by=5466&mode=long - it is a png image
I've tried with the following codes

```
*/5 *   *   *   *   curl http://servlet.dmi.dk/byvejr/servlet/byvejr_dag1?by=5466&mode=long > /home/klintweb/public_html/gal.klintmx.dk/images/vejr.png
```

The image is saved in the folder, but it can't be published because of an error - the file-size is 0 byte
Is there a way to do this

Comment: Most probably you need to escape the `&` --> http://stackoverflow.com/q/16238460/1983854

Answer (score 0):

The job is done with a php script

```
$profile_Image = 'http://servlet.dmi.dk/byvejr/servlet/byvejr_dag1?by=5466&mode=long'; //image url
$userImage = 'byvejr_dag1_5466.png'; // renaming image
$path = '/home/klintweb/public_html/gal.klintmx.dk/images/vejr';  // your saving path
$ch = curl_init($profile_Image);
$fp = fopen($path . $userImage, 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

and this CRON job

```
0,30    *   *   *   *   /usr/bin/php /home/klintweb/public_html/gal.klintmx.dk/byvejr.php
```

and this .htaccess in the folder images/vejr to make sure it's not cached

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# disable caching forthis directory mod_expires for this directory
ExpiresActive off
</IfModule>
```

Comment: @fedorqui might have a point, but partly the answer is written after my own answer to the question, and secondly, fedorqui writes nothing about how to escape the &
My answer is a complete answer to the question - and it works perfect, even there could be others